# Is there an easy way to find the lowest and highest number in a set of variables with values? (Bash script) (Linux)

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
for i in {1..10}
do
      read integer”$i”
done
sum=$((integer1+integer2+integer3+integer4+integer5+integer6+integer7+integer8+integer9+integer10))
echo Sum is $sum
```

I don't know how to find the highest/lowest of the 10 variables and output them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute the sum, max and min on the fly, as you would do in any programming language. And prefer a more convenient indexed array to store your integers (access their value with `${integer[1]}, ${integer[2]},...`):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash
declare -ai integer=()
declare -i max min sum
for i in {1..10}; do
  read integer[i]
  if (( i == 1 )); then
    max="${integer[i]}"
    min="${integer[i]}"
    sum="${integer[i]}"
  else
    (( max = integer[i] > max ? integer[i] : max ))
    (( min = integer[i] < min ? integer[i] : min ))
    (( sum += integer[i] ))
  fi
done
printf 'max is %d\n' "$max"
printf 'min is %d\n' "$min"
printf 'sum is %d\n' "$sum"
```